# Eliminar primer elemento con JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Uso la etiqueta `<video>` para poder reproducir una lista de vídeos en mi pagina web, para lograr esto se me ocurrió cargar la lista de videos usando `<source>` dentro de `<video>` después usar el evento `ended` combinado con el atributo `loop` para que al terminar de reproducirse el primer vídeo usar `JavaScrip` y remover el primer `<source>` y como cuenta con el atributo `loop` reproducir automáticamente el `<source>` que en este caso sería el segundo de la lista ya que el primero fue eliminado al terminar de reproducirse y repetir este proceso hasta que se terminen todas las etiquetas `source`, por el momento cuento con esto:

```
<video autoplay preload="auto" muted controls loop id="vid" width="100%">
    <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="videos/video3.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

var reprod = document.getElementById("vid");
reprod.onended = function() {
    //Aquí deseo borrar el primer elemento source dentro del elemento video
};
```

Mi consulta es ¿cómo puedo remover la primer etiqueta `<source>` de la lista usando `JavaScript` o `JQuery`? y si mi idea general para lograr esto es correcta.

**AGREGADO:** Para tratar de eliminar el primer source traté algo como esto

```
var reprod = document.getElementById("vid");
var srcs = reprod.getElementByTagName("source");
reprod.onended = function() {
    reprod.removeChild(srcs[0]);
};
```

Comment: Agrega una breve descripción de lo que has buscado/investigado como se sugiere en [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno de los problemas es `loop`, cuando este control está presente no se ejecuta el evento `ended` (al menos en algunos navegadores). Otro problema es que cuando haces `reprod.getElementByTagName("source")` estando fuera de la función siempre vas a tratar de eliminar el mismo elemento, aunque ya no exista. Una posible solución sería algo como:

```
const reprod = document.getElementById("vid");

reprod.addEventListener('ended',function(){
       const sources = document.getElementsByTagName("source"); 
       this.removeChild(sources[0]);//<-- Es el primer elemento en cada loop
       this.play();//<-- Para reemplazar loop
})
```

Answer (score 2):

En general [`<source>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/source) es usado para disponer al usuario distintos formatos de audio/video, lo cual no parece que estés haciendo en tu código.

Creo que una forma distinta sería que controlaras el `src` de tu video en el evento `ended`. Aquí un ejemplo de como cambiarlo cuando termina de reproducirse el primer video:

```js
const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  console.log('video actual', event.target.src);
  if( event.target.src != 'https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/canvas/chroma-keying/media/video.mp4'){
    event.target.src = 'https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/canvas/chroma-keying/media/video.mp4'
  }
      
});
```

```html
<video src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.mp4" autoplay width="250" muted>
</video>
```